# Can I use `screen` to keep an ssh tunnel alive from the client?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127369/how-to-prevent-write-failed-broken-pipe-on-ssh-connection#answer-196447) that you can keep your ssh sessions alive a bit longer using a utility called GNU screen.  Is it possible to keep an SSH tunnel alive longer with this as well?

Comment: If you want to keep ssh sessions alive, the better solution is to use the `ServerAliveInterval` ssh setting. It's the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Patrick I don't think I have access to that setting.

Comment: You have access to `~/.ssh/config`. At least I certainly hope you do :-). And if you don't, then `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=600 ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tunnel terminates for any reason, screen won't restart it. I've found [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) works really well for managing tunnels - it can can monitor and restart them when necessary. It's ideal for starting tunnels from init scripts, for example.